# 502- Web server received an invalid responses

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

Sometimes i got a 502 error on my azure Application, so  i've turned on diagnostic logging in my server.
It shows me 2 errors( youc can find them as attached images): the first one

[404.0 not found. I don't know why the server was looking for that. I don't have the ressource in my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nHbl.png)

[the second: 404.15 Not found the query string is too long. It happens when i upload document. I've set up my web config to load max 2Go of document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpNKL.png)

```
<system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151" /></system.web>
<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering><requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxQueryString="3000"/>
```

do you have any idea?

thank you

Comment: Are you using the Azure App Service - Web App?  What pricing tier are you using?

Comment: Yes  i'm using Azure App Service-Web App. Standard S2 as pricing tier.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is probably because somewhere in your html/css you have ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png referenced but you did not include it in the correct position in your project. Are you using jquery-ui by any chance?

The second one is most likely caused by the groupsToken which expands as you add the client to more groups via SignalR. Do you have an upload status or something on the page? Are you using angular/knockout on that page? If so then you need to make sure that when the upload finishes you deregister from the group giving you the information.

Comment: Indeed ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png was call from jquery.ui.css. 
for the second one: i use AsyncFileUpload from AjaxToolkit with no upload status, only a loading image while the file is submitting

Comment: Do you use signalR in any way on your website?

Comment: Yes. I've it in my MasterPage,but i don't call it in that content page( used to publish document). May be i've to place SignalR in all content pages where i whant to use it.

Comment: That, most likely, explains the second error message.